# proof $f(x,y)=g_1(x)g_2(y)$ is differentiable in $(x,y)=(0,$0) if $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are differentiable at $ x=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $g_1,g_2: ]-1,1[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable in $0$.

Show that $f: (-1,1)^2 \to \mathbb{R}, f(x,y) = g_1(x) g_2(y)$ is differentiable in $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

So far I have

\begin{align*}
  &\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h_1, h_2) - f(0, 0) - J_f(0, 0)h}{||h||}\\
  &= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g_1(h_1) g_2(h_2) - g_1(0) g_2(0) - g'_1(0) g_2(0) h_1 - g_1(0) g'_2(0) h_2}{||h||}\\
  &= \lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{g_1(h_1)g_2(h_2)}{||h||} - \lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{g_1(0)g_2(0)}{||h||} - \lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{g_1'(0)g_2(0)h_1}{||h||} - \lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{g_2'(0)g_1(0)h_2}{||h||}
 \end{align*}

Any ideas how to continue?

Comment: Hint: Try adding and subtracting something in the numerator.

Comment: We have $$ g_1(h_1)g_2(h_2)- g_1(0)g_2(0) = (g_1(0)+g_1'(0)h_1+o(h_1))(g_2(0)-g_2'(0)h_2 +o(h_2)) -g_1(0)g_2(0).$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven sry I'm not seeing how this helps ... also where're the $o(h_1)$ and $o(h_2)$ coming from and what are they?

Comment: It is not helpful to re-write a convergent limit into a linear combination of divergent limits.

Comment: @GEdgar ok, in what should I re-write it then, I really have no idea

Comment: Another hint: Write the definition of $g_1, g_2$ being differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor that $g_1, g_2$ are being differentiable at $0$ means that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g_i(0 + h) - g_i(0)}{h} = g'_i(0)$ exists but how does that help me?

Comment: The small $o$ come from the differentiabiliy of $g_1, g_2$. Indeed, being differentiable in $0$ is equivalent to saying $$g_1(h_1)=g_1(0)+g_1'(0)h_1 + o(h_1).$$ It helps, because with this we get $$g_1(h_1)g_2(h_2) -g_1(0)g_2(0) - g_1'(0)h_1g_2(0) - g_1(0)g_2'(0)h_2 = -(g_1'(0)h_1+o(h_1))(g_2'(0) h_2 + o(h_2))=o(\vert h\vert).$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $g_1, g_2$ are differentiable at $0$, then
$$\lim_{h_i \to 0}\frac{g_i(h_i) - g_i(0) - g_i'(0) h_i}{h_i} = 0.$$
You want to add and subtract something in the numerator to write
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h_1, h_2) - f(0, 0) - g_1'(0) g_2(0) h_1 - g_1(0) g_2'(0) h_2}{\rVert h\rVert}$$
in terms of (or, at least, "almost" in terms of) the above two limits.

Comment: I tried the other suggested idea and have the following:

Comment: $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g_1(h_1) g_2(h_2) - g_1(0) g_2(0) - g'_1(0) g_2(0) h_1 - g_1(0) g'_2(0) h_2}{||h||}$
$= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(g_1(0) + g'_1(0)h_1 + o(h_1))(g_2(0) + g'_2(0)h_2 + o(h_2)) - g_1(0)g_2(0) - g'_1(0)g_2(0)h_1 - g_1(0)g'_2(0)h_2}{||h||}$
$= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(g'_1(0)h_1 + o(h_1))(g'_2(0)h_2 + o(h_2)) + g_1(0)o(h_2) + g_2(0)o(h_1)}{||h||}$
$= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{o(h)}{||h||}$

and because the limes exists $f$ is differentiable. Does that work like that @themathandlanguagetutor ?

Comment: @SeverinSchravin What do you think? I'm not comfortable enough with little-o notation to say.

Comment: @Felix That said, your conclusion should be that the limit is $0$, not just that it exists.

Comment: thank you, so $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{o(h)}{||h||} = 0$ ... but what's about the little o notation? I learned that as one of the definitions of differentiability ... though I'm not sure if the limes actually exists... isn't it more a $\frac{0}{0}$ thing?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Sorry, I just realised I spelt your name wrong.